# remove wayback toolbar code in bewteen lines

Tags: grep, find, sed, xargs

I am trying to remove Wayback toolbar code using some tools such as find & xargs and grep with sed etc

issue that the size of the html & php files it's over 7GB & as well as the pages over (3 millions page) I want to do it for all pages that begin with Wayback tooldbar which I've downloaded from  web.archive.org.
the good thing that the wayback toolbar code is start & end with

```
<!-- BEGIN WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT -->
 Wayback tooldbar code
 bla bla bla 
<!-- END WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT -->
```

but no order in which line..So, i try with the below command

```
find . -type f -name '*.php*' | xargs -I {} grep -l '<!-- BEGIN WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT -->' '{}'
```

i can catch those files that contain the toolbar

but I've stuck in the how to remove the code in between < start and end>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use sed to delete that stuff:

```
find ... -print0 | 
xargs -0 sed -i '/BEGIN WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT/,/END WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve an unmodified copy of HTML documents from the Wayback Machine by appending `id_` to the snapshot date/time in the URL.

For example:

With toolbar: https://web.archive.org/web/20180101010338/http://www.example.com:80/

Raw original: https://web.archive.org/web/20180101010338id_/http://www.example.com:80/

Answer (score -1):

On macOS:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e '/BEGIN WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT/,/END WAYBACK TOOLBAR INSERT/d' {} \;
```

macOS specifically needs an empty string passed in as an argument to -i because they use the BSD version of find instead of the GNU version on linux so there are some differences. I can't find the stackoverflow post on it now, but I'm sure it could be searched for.

Comment: This looks fairly similar to the accepted answer. Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: macOS find tool requires an extra argument, the double quotations ('') in order to work. Using the first answer, you encounter the following error: `find: ...: No such file or directory`. The find0 argument looks incorrect as well (or at least I was not able to get it working). There was another answer (that I cannot find now) that says you have to pass an empty string to the -i function specifically on macOS. Using this answer, you are able to traverse through all the files. It is unfortunate that the working answer is downvoted.

Comment: (1) In English (and a bunch of other languages, I believe), “**...**” means “and so on”, “whatever”, “blah blah blah”, or similar things — it’s a placeholder.  It’s a shame that glenn used **`...`** as a placeholder for ``. -type f -name '*.php*'`` (or whatever `find` arguments you want to use), but I’m sure he didn’t mean for users to type “**`.` `.` `.`**” literally.  (2) If you typed “find0”, it’s no wonder it didn’t work, because glenn didn’t say “find0”.  (3) If you would [edit] your answer to include the explanation you just posted in the above comment  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (specifically, the part(s) about `sed -i`, maybe stated in a bit more detail, and not the parts about `...` and “find0”, which are just reflections of your misunderstanding, and maybe add something about `-exec` vs. `xargs`), it might get upvoted.  (4) `find .` is just as good as `find ./`.  I would advise against using `find ./` because, if you get into the habit of typing that, it’s too easy to type ```find /``` by accident.  Murphy’s Law says that you will make that error at a time when it will cause the most damage possible.

Comment: updated original answer to include an explanation.